# Dataset summation in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R with two columns labelled x and y each with over 1000 values. I need to find `sum((xi^2-xbar^2)(yi-ybar))/sum((xi-xbar)^4)` for a linear regression problem. All I can think to use is:

```
sum(((data$x)^2-mean(data$x)^2)(data$y-mean(data$y)))/sum((data$x-mean(data$x))^4)
```

But this just gives me `Error: attempt to apply non-function`. I haven't got a clue how to correct this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use both `data$x` and `x` by itself (and similarly for y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: How do you figure out what the problem is in an expression that is visually overwhelming?

Answer: take it apart piece by piece.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
df$x^2
# works fine 
df$x^2 - mean(x)^2
# works fine **SEE NOTE** 
sum(df$x^2 - mean(x)^2)
# works fine
# sum(DF$x^2 - mean(x)^2)(data$y-mean.... oh i see
```

You're trying to multiply by putting parens next to each other. Use `*`

NOTE: NO IT DOESN'T ... on a second pass, you might discover that your values aren't correct, but this isn't what throws the error if you have an x object already in your environment (and that object doesn't have any NA values)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the () and how you refer x and y variable from data. Try the following.

```
sum(((data$x)^2-(mean(data$x))^2)*(data$y-mean(data$y)))/sum((data$x-(mean(data$x))^2))
```